# Profile python in google app engine sdk (djangoappengine)

Tags: profiling, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I am developing a dDango app (djangoappengine) using the Google App Engine SDK. My app is painfully slow and I want to profile it. I have tried cProfile, profile, and hotshot according to

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango

However, due to (I think) Google's limited offering of pre-installed python-libs. all tries result in some `ImpportError`. That is, cProfile, profile etc. are installed on  the computer, but not "usable" when running my app using the GAE SDK.

I have tried symlinking cProfile directly into my app (as if I had written it myself), but that only brings other problems.

**Is there a real way to profile a djangoappengine app without too much hassle?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symlinking route is the way to go.

You can use AppStats for profiling App Engine API calls.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

This is generally useful, since generally the bottlenecks will be on datastore requests etc.  This won't help you if you have your own compute intensive loops to profile.